# Using regexp to find a word

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a tweet and I need to find what the hashtags say.  How can I isolate and save to a variable everything that starts with a '#' and ends with a ' ' using regexp?  I'm using MatLab.

Comment: I read through the help file for the regexp command and found the matchstart and matchend commands but I'm not sure how to implement them or if they're even the right things to be using.

Comment: @all: Sometimes, there are users who genuinely don't know where to start. Unlike others, this question is actually very clear - how to use regexp to find a hashtag, and the user (in the comments) tells us they did RTFM. Consequently, I vote to re-open the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions can be challenging to use when you're not familiar with them.

Here's one way to find a hashtag:

```
tweet = 'it is fun to post on #stackoverflow, really';
regexp(tweet,'#(\w+)','tokens','once')
ans = 
    'stackoverflow'
```

What does `#(\w+)` do? We look "word"-characters (no spaces, no punctuation) with `\w`, and specify that we want at least one of them `+`. The word has to start with a `#`. We use the parentheses to indicate which part we want to be returned, and the option `tokens` so that it returns the match (I don't care where the hashtag is in the tweet). I set the option `once` so that `regexp` only looks for one hashtag; don't do that if you expect multiple hashtags in your tweet, though note that the output will be a cell array of strings.