# Extracting strings from cells in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using regexp to find a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829563/using-regexp-to-find-a-word)

I'm working on an assignment for my CS course.
We're given a plain text file, which, in my case, contains a series of tweets.
What I need to do is create a script that will detect hashtags, and then save each hashtag into an cell array.

So far I know how to write a function that detects the '#' symbol...

```
strfind(textRead{i},'#');
```

where in a for loop where i=1:30 (that is, the number of cells of text). However, past that, I'm at a loss as to how I should write a script that will detect the '#' and return the text between that and the next ' ' (space) character.

Comment: regexp seems more suitable than a simple strfind, because you want to find the word after the hash and not the hash itself ;) [this is probably useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex)

Comment: Some other people seem to have the same assignment. Look for the answers they got.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
str = '#someHashtag other tweet text ignore #random';
regexp(str, '#[A-z]*', 'match')
```

I think you'll be able to find the rest out yourself :)

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do! Thanks! I don't really know how it works though...

Comment: @user1902116: It's the magic of [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)! I strongly suggest you learn them, and learn them well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is basic skeleton. But make sure to use correct regexp to extract the values ;-)

Yes with the above Dorin's regexp and match you get one value at a time. You may add a `token` as per this example from mathworks.
 Sample:

```
str = ['if <code>A </code> == x<sup>2 </sup>, ' ... '<em>disp(x) </em>'] 
str = if <code>A </code> == x<sup>2 </sup>, <em>disp(x) </em> 
expr = '<(\w+).*?>.*?</\1>';
[tok mat] = regexp(str, expr, 'tokens', 'match'); 
tok{:}
ans = 'code' 
ans = 'sup' 
ans = 'em'
```

in above code you don't really need to loop and can process entire text bulk as one string , hopefully not hitting any string limit......
But if you want to loop, or if you need to loop, you use the following sample with Rody's regexp and match only.

```
 fid = fopen('data.txt'); 
 dataText = fgetl(fid);
 while ~feof(fid) 
    ldata = textscan(dataText,'*%d#*'); 
          X = (ldata, '#[A-z]*', 'match') 
         Cellarray =  X{1}      
   end
  Disp(X)
 fclose(fid);
```